# How to float search icon to the right

Tags: html, css

How do i float the font awesome search icon to the right next to sign up.

Here is a screenshot of my nav bar, so you know what i am referring too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIGzP.jpg

I have search the internet for tutorials and they all say to use float: right; but that seems to not work

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 130px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav-menu a img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin-top: -130px;
}

.nav-menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.nav-menu li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu li.social {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width:50px"></a>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Crews</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="social">
      <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      <a href="#" style="color:#ff0000">Sign Up</a>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li></a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Side note, yout HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<a>` as a child of `<ul>`

Comment: Try changing: <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li></a> to <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `<li>` wrapping the search icon. This is an invalid code. `<li>` cannot be a children of an `<li>`. Change it to just an `<a>` element

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 130px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav-menu a img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin-top: -130px;
}

.nav-menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.nav-menu li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu li.social {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width:50px"></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Crews</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="social">
      <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      <a href="#" style="color:#ff0000">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to add that, but it worked, thank you

Comment: This is also invalid, the li of social is missing the end </li>

Comment: @imvain2, little mistake fixed

Comment: This HTML is invalid also

Comment: @j08691, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the question - but I have an improved solution (at least I think so)!

The syntax on the previous answer is still a little incorrect. You should also try to make your dropdowns into nested `ul`'s. :-)

By using the `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the `.nav-menu`, you will be aligning all the elements up without the use of `float` (which I tend to avoid anyway as it often makes your code behave like you would not expect).

I've also added `margin-left:auto` for you on your `.social` container, it will push all your social to the end of the parent.

**EDIT:**
If you use `border-top: transparent` on the menu items, this makes sure that the text doesn't move when you add in a coloured border on `:hover` - so you're essentially just showing the colour.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.nav-menu img {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav-menu>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul.social {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-menu li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.nav-menu li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!-- just for the example -->

<div class="nav-menu">
  <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width:50px"></a>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Crews</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="social">
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="color:#ff0000">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see the full effect if you view the snippet in full screen.